# React native - highlight an icon in a "fizzy" way

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c43i.png)

Does anyone know how to achieve this effect?

Comment: Have you tried doing something? Please enter us your code so we will help better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware if there is an easier solution but my approach would be using something like https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-blur

What you can do is have a normal view in place of your current icon

This view will have a blur view and an icon with absolute position on top of it.
You can toggle the visibility of the blur view based on the selected tab and that should achieve the result you want.